# OGR2OGR FileGDB 2 other format with -SQL query change structure

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm using GDAL 1.11.1 with ESRI FileGDB Driver, GDB version 10.x.

When I use ogr2ogr, my goal is to sort differently my fields and in some case, to rename them. The problem is when I call FileGDB driver to an other format, my table structure change for every strings.

For example:

- Input FileGDB :string field, 3 of length
- Output FileGDB:string field, all fields are set to 0 (ogrinfo) or 65536 (ArcGIS 10.1)
- Output SHP:string field, every field is set to 80 (by ogrinfo)

here my cmd.
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" TEMP.GDB Source.gdb -sql "select * from input_layer"

I have tried to do an ALTER TABLE nation ALTER COLUMN myfield2 TYPE character(15) but it's do not work on FileGDB?

Any ideas?

Comment: Reporting a ticket to gdal. Follow the issue with https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been closed an fixed in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5806